# Apache Kerberos Authentication - Client didn't delegate us their credential

Tags: apache, active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to use mod_auth_kerb to log in users into my website automatically against an AD server running on W2008 Server. Users are already logged in a windows network, and access to the website.

My virtual server conf is:

```
<Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Satisfy Any
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName "Kerberos Login ORN"
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
        KrbServiceName Any
        KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.ES
        Krb5KeyTab /etc/krb5.keytab
        require valid-user
</Location>
```

I succesfully login via kinit from apache:

```
kinit -t /etc/HTTP-hesl035.keytab
Password for HTTP-hesl035@EXAMPLE.ES:

klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: HTTP-hesl035@EXAMPLE.ES

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
11/07/13 17:55:46  11/08/13 03:55:51  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ES@EXAMPLE.ES
        renew until 11/08/13 03:55:46
```

or

```
kinit HTTP-hesl035
Password for HTTP-hesl035@EXAMPLE.ES:

klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: HTTP-hesl035@EXAMPLE.ES

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
11/07/13 17:57:26  11/08/13 03:57:26  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ES@EXAMPLE.ES
        renew until 11/08/13 03:57:26
```

I configure firefox with the settings:

```
network.negotiate-auth.delegation.uris = testing.example.es
network.negotiate-auth.trusted.uris = testing.example.es
```

When I access to the site I get an Authoritation Required.

1st Header sent by browser is:

```
GET Host: testing.example.es
```

1st Header response by server is:

```
401 Authorization required
WWW-authenticate: Negotiate
```

2nd header sent by browser is:

```
GET Host: testing.example.es
Authentication: Negotiate {TOKEN}
```

2nd header sent by server is:

```
401 Athorization required
```

Apache log saying the following:

```
Thu Nov 07 18:06:09 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1939): [client 192.168.4.16] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Thu Nov 07 18:06:09 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1939): [client 192.168.4.16] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Thu Nov 07 18:06:09 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1691): [client 192.168.4.16] Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API
[Thu Nov 07 18:06:09 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1707): [client 192.168.4.16] Client didn't delegate us their credential
[Thu Nov 07 18:06:09 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1735): [client 192.168.4.16] Warning: received token seems to be NTLM, which isn't supported by the Kerberos module. Check your IE configuration.
[Thu Nov 07 18:06:09 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1138): [client 192.168.4.16] GSS-API major_status:00010000, minor_status:00000000
[Thu Nov 07 18:06:09 2013] [error] [client 192.168.4.16] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: An unsupported mechanism was requested (, Unknown error)
```

Using krbtray.exe on the users windows machine i see the following tickets:

```
EXAMPLE.ES
- host/minit-bn-example.es
- krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ES
```

I get the krbtgt/EXAMPLE.ES when I visit the apache app.

Seems that the client is sending the kerberos ticket, but not sure of it. Anyone knows about this issue??

EDIT:

If I set KrbMethodK5Passwd to On in my apache conf, I get a popup with user/pass form when accessing the web app. But I cannot login with user credentials.

Apache log says:

```
[Thu Nov 07 17:41:34 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1939): [client 192.168.4.16] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Thu Nov 07 17:41:34 2013] [error] [client 192.168.4.16] Error parsing server name (Any): Hostname cannot be canonicalized
[Thu Nov 07 17:41:34 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1110): [client 192.168.4.16] kerb_authenticate_user_krb5pwd ret=401 user=(NULL) authtype=(NULL)
```

If I use wireshark in windows client to fetch packets, I get 2 kerberos errors from the AD to the windows client:

```
KRB Error: KRB5KRB_ERR_RESPONSE_TOO_BIG
KRB Error: KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN error is due to a bad generated map file with ktpass.exe in the AD server.

Generate a correct map file with ktpass.exe as this:

```
ktpass -princ HTTP/example.es@EXAMPLE.ES -mapuser username\HTTP-hesl035 -crypto ALL -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -mapop set -pass password -out c:\tem
p\krb5.keytab
```

And assign the user a SPN with setspn.exe in the AD server:

```
setspn -s HTTP/example.es HTTP-hesl035
```

- HTTP-hesl035 is apache server username created in AD.